# Problema com a formatação do print em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse código é pra resover um problema do URI,o 1179, ele dá presentation error, por que há um espaço nas respostas, entre os colchetes, o problema está nos prints dentro dos laços **for**. Tem como imprimir sem os espaços? Tipo lista[indice]  e não lista[ indice ] que é, como aparece?

```
par = []
impar = []

cont = 0
while cont < 15:
    n = int(input())
    if n % 2 == 0:
        par.append(n)
        if len(par) == 5:
            for i, pares in enumerate(par):
                print("par[",i,"] =", pares)
            par.clear()
    else:
        impar.append(n)
        if len(impar) ==5:
            for i, impares in enumerate(impar):
                print("impar[",i,"]=", impares)
            impar.clear()

    cont += 1
for i, impares in enumerate(impar):    
    print("impar[",i,"]=", impares)
for i, pares in enumerate(par):
    print("par[",i,"] =", pares)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você passa vários parâmetros para o [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), por padrão ele coloca um espaço entre esses parâmetros. Mas você pode mudar esse comportamento passando o parâmetro `sep`:

```
for i, impares in enumerate(impar):    
    print("impar[",i,"]=", impares, sep='')
for i, pares in enumerate(par):
    print("par[",i,"] =", pares, sep='')
```

Assim ele usa a string vazia (`''`) entre os elementos, ou seja, não terá mais espaços.

Mas há alternativas melhores, como o [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
 print("par[{}]={}".format(i, pares))
```

Ou, a partir do Python 3.6, com [*f-string*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
 print(f"par[{i}]={pares}")
```

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas sugiro dar nomes melhores para as variáveis, pois [isso ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Por exemplo, as listas poderiam ter os nomes no plural (`impares` e `pares`), pois elas podem ter mais de um número. E nos *loops* a variável pode ter o nome no singular, pois a cada iteração ela representa um número. Ou seja:

```
pares = []

...
for i, par in enumerate(pares):
    print(f"par[{i}]={par}")
```

Ou ainda:

```
for i, numero in enumerate(pares):
    print(f"par[{i}]={numero}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu ja tive esse mesmo erro, e resolvi usando os fstrings. coloque seus prints nesse formato

```py
for i, impares in enumerate(impar):
    print(f"impar[{i}]=", impares)
```

Neste formato os espaços não aparecem.